# Correct wrong occurrences in a string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, replace, rtf

Buggy control provides in text something like this:

```
{{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK http://yandex.ru }}{\fldrslt{http://yandex.ru\ul0\cf0}}}}\f0\fs24
```

but correct version is:

```
{{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK http://yandex.ru }}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 http://yandex.ru}}}}\f0\fs24
```

I'm really newbie in regex and other text tools, so I don't know how replace all occurrences with correct variant in righteous way. We can't rewrite control logic now, there is more WinAPI code. 
Platform is .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: I'm generated the regex query at http://www.regexr.com/3af31, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Well, based on your description - why don't just remove `\ul0\cf0`and then append `\ul\cf1` to the beginning? Pretty simple and no regular expressions needed.

Comment: Wrong data occurred in text few more times and with different «somesite.com». 
I'm trying to find good way to get all wrong occurrences from text to replace.

Comment: this https://regex101.com/r/dO5zI3/5 ?

Comment: Probably you need to specify your problem more precisely and provide your actual input and desired output. Right now I see only some character sequence at the end to remove and some other sequence to add at the beginning. It doesn't matter what is the rest of string.

Comment: Updated. 
@Avinash Raj your regex failed to in .Matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically regular expression you've generated is ok, as it does in job and find all occurences like `{http://yandex.com\ul0\cf0}`.

If I have understood your goal correctly - the only transformation you need in each capture group - is transform `{http://yandex.com\ul0\cf0}` to `{\ul\cf1  http://yandex.com}`.

This can be done easily with [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) override having [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as argument.

For example, something like this (note, it is not most elegant solution, rather it is "quick and dirty"):

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(source_Text, regex_pattern,
                x => x.Groups[0].Value.Replace(@"\ul0\cf0", "").Replace("{", @"{\ul\cf1 "));
```

Comment: Edited pattern and now all OK. 
Thanks thou, Developer.